# Compute hash of a substring given the hashes of all prefixes of the string

Tags: java, string, algorithm, hash

Suppose you are given a string `S` of length `N` and also an array of hash values of all the prefixes of the string `S` `hash[0][0...N-1]`.

`hash[0][i]` denotes the hash of the prefix of string `S` ending at index `i`. `M` denotes a large prime integer. `R` denotes a radix used in the hash function.

You are also given the hash function used:

```
for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    hash[0][i] = ( (i > 0 ? hash[0][i - 1] : 0) * R + S.charAt(i) ) % M;
}
```

We need to compute the `hash[i][j]` on a need basis. Can we find out the hash value of a substring of `S` in `O(1)` i.e. `hash[i][j]` given the above information?

`where, i,j > 0 and i,j < N`

Note: The array `hash[][]` initially contains only the precomputed hashes `hash[0][0....N-1]` of the prefixes of string `S`.

Answer (score 2):

The hash of the substring s[A..B] is

```
hash[B] - R^(B - A + 1) * hash[A - 1] mod M
```

Use modular exponentiation to compute the power of R mod M. And no, unless you precomputed the powers of R it is not possible to compute that in O(1).